# GSAP ScrollMagic - setPin() is bugging

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I am asking here cause I can't debug my program.
I wanted to do a page to scroll vertically and then scroll horizontally till the end of the 'test' section and then scroll vertically again.
The thing is that the setPin() doest work... its totally bugging

Can someone please help me ?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qua3omc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/ScrollMagic.min.js" integrity="sha512-8E3KZoPoZCD+1dgfqhPbejQBnQfBXe8FuwL4z/c8sTrgeDMFEnoyTlH3obB4/fV+6Sg0a0XF+L/6xS4Xx1fUEg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/animation.gsap.js" integrity="sha512-judXDFLnOTJsUwd55lhbrX3uSoSQSOZR6vNrsll+4ViUFv+XOIr/xaIK96soMj6s5jVszd7I97a0H+WhgFwTEg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js" integrity="sha512-RvUydNGlqYJapy0t4AH8hDv/It+zKsv4wOQGb+iOnEfa6NnF2fzjXgRy+FDjSpMfC3sjokNUzsfYZaZ8QAwIxg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenLite.min.js" integrity="sha512-pvDW4tehKKsohH97164HwKwRGFpzayEFWTVbk8HuUoLIQ7Jp+WLN5XYokVuoCj2aT6dy8ihbW8SRTG1k0W4mSQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TimelineLite.min.js" integrity="sha512-tSIDeirKC6suYILHqqPuZH3s0MvD4a5vCHXhBIcdmq4gQXZ2IB3fEYA5x2f3D2p/CbSqzKEvuTEVbS5VZ2u+ew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js" integrity="sha512-ocsFo48WU8Xq6Y1Lwi7psXRAujG9E4TKNR4q1DbrKzaaxOMTEoao/a+mDoB+cYzY4lwbyxvqjkp/ZA1/MNlfsg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <section id="test">
        <div class="big-bloc">
            <div class="bloc">

            </div>
            <div class="bloc">

            </div>
            <div class="bloc">

            </div>
            <div class="bloc">

            </div>
        </div>


    </section>


</body>

</html>

    <script>

const tweenbloc = new TimelineLite();

var bigbloc = document.getElementsByClassName('.big-bloc');
var width_bigbloc = bigbloc.offsetWidth;

tweenbloc.add(
    TweenLite.to('.bloc', 1, {
        xPercent: -400,


    })
)

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

const bloc_scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '.big-bloc',
        duration: 500,
        triggerHook: 0.2
    })
    .setTween(tweenbloc)
    .addIndicators()
    .setPin('#test')
    .addTo(controller);

</script>
```

My CSS

```
#test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: springgreen;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#test .big-bloc {
    background-color: wheat;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

#test .bloc {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: violet;
}
```

Thanks a lot by advance :)

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way. Same goes for using GSAP 3 over GSAP 2.

Comment: Hey Sach, Yeah you're right ! Thanks a lot ! Sorry I am just starting. Thanks for your time